# How can I select each particular data up to a certain quantity?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select each particular data upto a certain quantity. For example in the below table, there are 4 A, 4 B, 2 C and 1 D. Now I want to select all letters but not more than two each of it, Which will yield 2 A, 2 B, 2 C and 1 D.

```
+====+========+
| ID | Letter |
+====+========+
|  1 | A      |
+----+--------+
|  2 | B      |
+----+--------+
|  3 | B      |
+----+--------+
|  4 | C      |
+----+--------+
|  5 | A      |
+----+--------+
|  6 | A      |
+----+--------+
|  7 | C      |
+----+--------+
|  8 | B      |
+----+--------+
|  9 | B      |
+----+--------+
| 10 | D      |
+----+--------+
| 11 | A      |
+----+--------+
```

Can anyone please help me for the above scenario?

Comment: `CASE WHEN COUNT(*) < 2 THEN 2 ELSE COUNT(*) END` and `GROUP BY Letter`

Comment: Of course `CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 2 THEN 2 ELSE COUNT(*) END` and `GROUP BY Letter`

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a simple way:

```
select 
    case 
        when count(*) > 1 
            then 2 
        else count(*) 
    end,
    second_column
from your_table 
group by second_column;
```

This will give the result you want, but it won't really 'select ONLY two or less records' of each.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `ROW_NUMBER()` function and a derived table:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (id int, Letter varchar(1))

INSERT INTO myTable
VALUES (1,'A')
                ,(2,'B')
                ,(3,'B')
                ,(4,'C')
                ,(5,'A')
                ,(6,'A')                    
                ,(7,'C')
                ,(8,'B')
                ,(9,'B')
                ,(10,'D')
                ,(11,'A')

SELECT id, Letter
FROM
(SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Letter ORDER BY Letter) as rn
FROM myTable) myTable
WHERE rn = 1 or rn = 2
```

In essence, "cut" (`PARTITION`) the rows by Letters, and assign them each a number for its unique group, then pick the first two of each Letter.

Try it here:

http://rextester.com/WTKYCE51114

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER() function to tag each record the row number and PARTITION it BY (grouping by) letter and ORDER it BY (id)

```
SELECT id,
       letter
  FROM (SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY letter ORDER BY id) rnum
          FROM myTable
       ) t
 WHERE rnum <=2
```

Ordering it by id, you will have the first two instances of each letter in ascending order, thus you will have below result (note that id 1 and 5 are selected for A, 2 and 3 for B)

```
id  letter
1   A
5   A
2   B
3   B
4   C
7   C
10  D
```